# data disks on azure virtual machines

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

So I just started with azure. I have provisioned a virtual machine. Everything is set up and working and I can log on. My question involves data disks. They really aren't explained on the azure website, nor when I asked a question in their support forum.  Specifically, what is their actual purpose? Am I SUPPOSED to add a data disk to my virtual machine, to put any of my user data on? (i.e. am I supposed to leave the C: drive pristine with only the operating system? plus I know I have to leave the "temp" D: alone) Or is this optional, and I can just go ahead and utilize free space on the C: drive, such as for example putting my deployed demo websites in C: inetpub folder, etc. (I am only using the vm to put small technology demos on it with relatively small amounts of data). And if I DO add a data disk to my vm, does that cost more money? If so, how much? I couldn't figure THAT out on the azure website either (the specific pricing impact of adding a data disk to the vm). Those questions are enough to start with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to answer your questions:

1. Data disks are optional to use but highly recommended if you have any form of custom data you would like to keep in the event you deprovision the VM (see next point).
2. If you use C:\ drive you will make it hard to transport the data to a new virtual machine in the event that you wish to change instance size or region.
3. Don't use D:\ for any persistent data.  D:\ gets erased between VM reboots.
4. Adding data disks costs nothing on the VM but it will cost you in terms of blob storage for the VHD as well as transactions to read / write to the VHD.  The exact cost is based on size of the VHD and how heavily it is used.

HTH.